# Changing the image of image view present in adapter on network changes

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, broadcastreceiver

I know how to change the UI when there is change in network connectivity which is very easy if we want to change `ui` of `activity`. I am using `VerticalView Pager Adapter` for my `ViewPager`.

I want to change the `imageview's` image which is located in the adapter class depending on the network connectivity. My Adapter class looks something like below

```
class VerticlePagerAdapter(private val mContext: Context, private val newsArrayList: ArrayList<News?>) : PagerAdapter() {

    private var mLayoutInflater: LayoutInflater =
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return newsArrayList.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object`
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false)

        val title = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_content_main_title)
        val imageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_content_main)
        val description = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_content_main_description)
        val progressBar = itemView.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)


        title.text = newsArrayList[position]?.title ?: "Sorry No Title Found"


            GlideApp.with(mContext).load(newsArrayList[position]?.imageUrl)
                    .error(R.mipmap.nointernet).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).listener(object:RequestListener<Drawable>{
                        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            return false
                        }

                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            return false
                        }

                    }).into(imageView)
       

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    return false
                }

            }).into(imageView)

        }

        description.text = newsArrayList[position]?.description ?: "Sorry No Description Found"

        container.addView(itemView)

        return itemView
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as ConstraintLayout)
    }

}
```

Following is my code to change the ui for network changes but it is for activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyReceiver myReceiver;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);

        IntentFilter customFilter = new IntentFilter(MyReceiver.NOTIFY_NETWORK_CHANGE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mLocalReceiver,customFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    }


    private BroadcastReceiver mLocalReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         boolean isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(MyReceiver.EXTRA_IS_CONNECTED,false);
         if(isConnected){
             //chnage the ui
         }else{
             //change the ui
         }
        }
    };
}
```

If I use the above code in my adapter how to get the position parameter for my `image view` in `onReceive` of `mLocalReceiver`.

Or is it possible to use the code in the activity itself and change the ui of adapter on network changes.
I know I can reload the activity when network changes but it is not a great user experience and not the right way to do so as user can clearly see that the activity is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the change in the network connection occurs. So your code stays the same, you just add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `mLocalReceiver#onReceive()` method.

The drawaback is that you, essentially, will ask the adapter to redraw each and every item, which might not be what you need. But, depending on the complexity of your screen, this solution might be good enough.

Comment: I tried doing that in the adapter but it does not work.

Comment: Why would you do it **in adapter**? The adapter does not have to anything regarding network connectivity, the adapter's task is to create views/populate them with data whenever needed. And your Activity/BroadcastReceiver is the place where you should be asking adapter to repopulate the list content.

Comment: Just add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onReceive() method and see what happens.

Comment: yeah I did that in the activity itself. It does not work. Let me try again and will get back to you